# D3 how to exclude links from Gooey effect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Problem:** The Gooey effect applies to the links too. Which creates a teardrop shaped frame instead of an circle.

The snipped contains a `dragged()` function which allows the user to *tear off* node 1 from node 0. Further it is possible to connect node 1 with node 0 again with the help of dragging. The code isn´t clean at all, as its a playground only.

**Goal**: How can I exclude the links from the Gooey effect in a way, that all links are displayed correctly and still achieve a proper circled shape. The *shape of the Gooey effect can be manipulated by changing the -5 to -40*, unfortunately it will hide the links completely:

```
.attr("values", "1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1  0 0 0 50 -5")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v6 Playground</title>
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .canvas {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }

    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node:hover {
        stroke: red
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        cursor: default;
        stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <svg id="svg"> </svg>

    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": 1,
                    "target": 0,
                },
                {
                    "source": 2,
                    "target": 0,
                },
            ]
        }

        var width = window.innerWidth
        var height = window.innerHeight

        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")
            .style("filter", "url(#gooey)")

        // remove zoom on dblclick listener
        d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

        var linkContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkContainer")
        var nodeContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodeContainer")

        var isSpliced = false;
        

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            }).distance(150))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(30))


        //###############################################
        //######### SVG Filter for Gooey effect #########
        //###############################################

        var defs = svg.append("defs");

        var filter = defs.append("filter").attr("id", "gooey");
        filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
            .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
            .attr("stdDeviation", "10")
            .attr("result", "blur");
        filter.append("feColorMatrix")
            .attr("in", "blur")
            .attr("mode", "matrix")
            .attr("values", "1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1  0 0 0 50 -5")
            .attr("result", "gooey");
        filter.append("feComposite")
            .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
            .attr("in2", "gooey")
            .attr("operator", "atop");

        initialize()

        //###############################################
        //############## Initialization #################
        //###############################################

        function initialize() {
            link = linkContainer.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("line")
                .attr("class", "link")

            node = nodeContainer.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
                .join("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            node.selectAll("circle")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("circle")
                .attr("r", 30)
                .style("fill", "white")

            node.selectAll("text")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("text")
                .style("class", "icon")
                .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 30)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "0px")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .text((d) => {
                    return d.id
                })

            simulation
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)
        }

        //###############################################
        //############# Update Positions ################
        //###############################################

        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            link
                .attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            // update node positions
            node
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                });
        }

        //###############################################
        //################ Drag Nodes ###################
        //###############################################

        var lineX;
        var lineY;
        var isPlugged = true;

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;

            lineX = d.x
            lineY = d.y
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;

            var root = graph.nodes.find(element => (element.id === 0))
            var distance = (root.x - d.x) * 2 + (root.y - d.y) * 2

            if (isPlugged && d.id === 1) {
                var indexOfLink = graph.links.findIndex(element => (element.source.id === d.id))

                if (distance < 0) {
                    distance = -distance
                }

                if (distance > 1000) {
                    graph.links.splice(indexOfLink, 1)
                    isPlugged = false;
                }

            } else {
                if (distance < 0) {
                    distance = -distance
                }
                if (distance < 20) {
                    graph.links.push({ source: d.id, target: root.id })
                    isPlugged = true;
                }
            }

            initialize()
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;

            link.filter((a) => {
                return a.source.id === d.id
            }).style("stroke", "black")
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the style to `nodeContainer` instead of `svg` - see comments below:

```
    var svg = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("class", "canvas")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
            svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
        }))
        .append("g") 
        // <--------- remove the style here

    // remove zoom on dblclick listener
    d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

    var linkContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkContainer")
    var nodeContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodeContainer")
        .style("filter", "url(#gooey)") // <---------- add the style here
```

Your code updated:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v6 Playground</title>
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .canvas {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }

    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node:hover {
        stroke: red
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        cursor: default;
        stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <svg id="svg"> </svg>

    <script>
        var graph = {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": 1,
                    "target": 0,
                },
                {
                    "source": 2,
                    "target": 0,
                },
            ]
        }

        var width = window.innerWidth
        var height = window.innerHeight

        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        // remove zoom on dblclick listener
        d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

        var linkContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkContainer")
        var nodeContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodeContainer")
            .style("filter", "url(#gooey)")

        var isSpliced = false;
        

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            }).distance(150))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(30))


        //###############################################
        //######### SVG Filter for Gooey effect #########
        //###############################################

        var defs = svg.append("defs");

        var filter = defs.append("filter").attr("id", "gooey");
        filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
            .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
            .attr("stdDeviation", "10")
            .attr("result", "blur");
        filter.append("feColorMatrix")
            .attr("in", "blur")
            .attr("mode", "matrix")
            .attr("values", "1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1  0 0 0 50 -5")
            .attr("result", "gooey");
        filter.append("feComposite")
            .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
            .attr("in2", "gooey")
            .attr("operator", "atop");

        initialize()

        //###############################################
        //############## Initialization #################
        //###############################################

        function initialize() {
            link = linkContainer.selectAll(".link")
                .data(graph.links)
                .join("line")
                .attr("class", "link")

            node = nodeContainer.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
                .join("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            node.selectAll("circle")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("circle")
                .attr("r", 30)
                .style("fill", "white")

            node.selectAll("text")
                .data(d => [d])
                .join("text")
                .style("class", "icon")
                .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 30)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "0px")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .text((d) => {
                    return d.id
                })

            simulation
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(graph.links)
        }

        //###############################################
        //############# Update Positions ################
        //###############################################

        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            link
                .attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            // update node positions
            node
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
                });
        }

        //###############################################
        //################ Drag Nodes ###################
        //###############################################

        var lineX;
        var lineY;
        var isPlugged = true;

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;

            lineX = d.x
            lineY = d.y
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;

            var root = graph.nodes.find(element => (element.id === 0))
            var distance = (root.x - d.x) * 2 + (root.y - d.y) * 2

            if (isPlugged && d.id === 1) {
                var indexOfLink = graph.links.findIndex(element => (element.source.id === d.id))

                if (distance < 0) {
                    distance = -distance
                }

                if (distance > 1000) {
                    graph.links.splice(indexOfLink, 1)
                    isPlugged = false;
                }

            } else {
                if (distance < 0) {
                    distance = -distance
                }
                if (distance < 20) {
                    graph.links.push({ source: d.id, target: root.id })
                    isPlugged = true;
                }
            }

            initialize()
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;

            link.filter((a) => {
                return a.source.id === d.id
            }).style("stroke", "black")
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to to apply this filter on specific nodes only? For example with nodeContainer.filter((a) => { return a.id === 1}).style("filter", "url(#gooey)")

Comment: I was reading about it here: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/ - so I guess if you put each node inside it's own `<g>` then you could apply to specific nodes ?